# How Can I change the Orientation for a div?

Tags: html

I have menu into a div, but perhaps I wanna change the orientation now is vertical, I already has one div under 2 divs. one of those subdivs are my menu. The code is this:

```
 .twoColFixLtHdr #sidebar1 {
    float: left;    padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;
```

What  can I put into float?

Comment: I try to be sympathetic to non-native english speakers, but I'm sorry to say your question is not very clear at all. Could you please attempt to give a more clear idea of what you're asking?

Comment: If by "orientation", you mean adjust the height and width... then just adjust the `height` and `width`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... It might help

```
float: left;
width:auto;
```